# C# autoit WinWaitActive not returning correct value

Tags: c#, autoit-c#-wrapper

I'm trying to get the information from a Messagebox that appears after a process runs in the GUI that I'm controlling with AutoIt v3. The messagebox will either show a success message or a fail message and I want to log those outcomes, but it keeps going to the 'failed install' rather than the 'success' and notes it in the log as a failure when I can see the message says success. Any help is appreciated. Here's my code along with my commented thoughts:

```
internal void Install(string filepath)
{
   au3.Send("!i"); //Send ALT+I
   au3.WinWaitActive("Select Content Package", "", 20000); //Wait for window
   au3.WinActivate("Select Content Package"); //If something else came up focus back on it prior to next line
   au3.MouseClick("primary", 337,11); //Click on field as AutoIt cannot access it.
   au3.Send(filepath);
   au3.Send("{Enter}");
   if(au3.WinWaitActive("Program", "successfully installed.", 90) == 1)
   { //WinWaitActive should return 1 if it is successful. The messagebox contains the text "successfully installed."
      au3.Send("{Enter}");
      writeLog(filepath + " Successfully installed.")
   }
   else
   { //WinWaitActive should return 0 if timeout, thus triggering this code
      au3.Send("{Enter}");
      writeLog(filepath + " Failed Install.")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue. The title in WinWaitActive() is case-sensitive and I missed a capitalization.